# Applying LVT Gluedown over non-flooring Hardwood ply

Tags: plywood, vinyl-flooring

I have got myself I to a bit of a bind with regard to my kitchen flooring (not the ground floor). I have floorboards, covered with soundproofing, covered in standard (not especially flooring) 9mm Hardwood throughout ply board.

Is there any way I can apply a skim coat to this and then put glue-down LVT on top of that, or will the moisture content be a problem with the plywood adhesive, making it peel up eventually? - what should I do to avoid ripping it all up and paying way more than I can afford to get it all redone properly?

Comment: Have you already bought your LVT?  If not, any reason you can't just pivot to floating?

Comment: What is "standard (not especially flooring) 9mm Hardwood throughout ply board"? The use of mm indicates you're likely not in the US (where a significant portion of your readers seem to be located), so linking to the product in question may help us answer your question. Additionally, _why_ do you need to apply a skim coat over this and what are you skim coating it with? If your surface isn't flat enough, you might be better off leveling under the "ply board" instead of on top of it.

Comment: I have listened to the comments and used them as a start to do more investigations and have decided to move to rigid core. I have also treated the plyboard for moisture resistance and mould reduction and screwed it down as much as I dare into the sound proofing. It is flat and stable. I think it's the best I can - I have bought the flooring so it's fingers crossed from here!